# Please help me to name this exercise!

Tags: weightlifting, gym, exercise-equipment

So essentially you get the olympic bar and then place a weight on one end and straddle the bar so that you can pick it up and then lift the weighted end towards your chest while the other end stays on the floor.

Comment: Can feel it working the back and upper chest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the [Bent Over Long Bar Row](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/bent-over-two-arm-long-bar-row) also known as a T-Bar row when using a handle (Thanks @wdika)?

[image: Bent Over Long Bar Row]

Comment: Correct answer although the common name is "T-bar Row", but it's just the other name of that excersice.

Comment: Added the T-bar row name, to me T-bar was always the machine, I didn't know it was called the same with the bar bell when you use a handle.